# Exception while displaying and scrolling large bitmaps in list view in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am facing this issue but unable to resolve. My problem goes like this:

- I have a list view. My list row contains an image view and one text view
- I have 20 images each of 12 MB size stored in my SD card
- I have to set these images in imageView of my list view

I am able to do it by following code. This I am doing in `getView` method of my custom adapter:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //other stuffs like recycling, view holder etc...
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inSampleSize = 4; // tried with 8,12 too
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri, opt);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return convertView;
}
```

Now this code works fine with small images but plays havoc for image of large size. Application crashes with `OutOfMemoryError`. If I try to increase `inSampleSize` to 8 or 12, it works but image quality drastically comes down and image doesn't look original image at all. I tried with `imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)` also but documentation suggests to use `setImageBitmap` only.

Now please someone help me to rectify this issue. How can I resolve this without compromising with image quality?

Comment: What are those images (12MB each)? What's the destination image dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting inSampleSize to 2 or 4, and scale width and height down using the `Matrix` class.
But as you said in another answer, this may hit performance.

```
float desiredWidth = 60; // the width you want your icon/image to be
float scale = desiredWidth/actualWidth // bitmap.getWidth() for actualWidth
// float scale = desiredHeight/actualHeight // If you want to go by a particular height

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false));
bitmap.recycle(); // ish
```

**Second option.** Before instantiating the Adapter class, get a Cursor object to thumbnail images and pass the cursor into the constructor of the adapter, making it a class varaible. Use the same cursor on every view row in the ListView.

```
Uri tUri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; // Where thumbnails are stored
String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,  MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

Cursor thumbCursor = this.managedQuery(tUri, null, null, null, null); // May want to use more paramaters to filter results
cursor.moveToFirst();

.... instantiate adapter, pass in cursor ....

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
cur.moveToNext();
// BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(listActivity.getResources(), filePath);
// holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Something like that. I did it in a hurry. Good luck  =)

Comment: Ok. I am trying and will get back to you.

Comment: I added a second option to my answer.

Comment: Tried both options but no success. :(

Answer (score 1):

A quick band-aid that might help would be to use:

```
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

That will load your images without an alpha channel, and only using 2 bytes per pixel (rather than 4 bytes with the default ARGB_8888).

Depending on the length of your list, you might have to load/unload your images as they become visible on screen/leave the screen.

Comment: It certainly improved the performance but still I am getting ANR while scrolling. Now I will try with loading/unloading logic.
+1 for nice thought. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating scale factor based on the image dimensions and call [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) to release memory allocated

Comment: If I recycle the images and next time if I scroll the list, it throws exception: Trying to use recycled image.

Comment: you have to re-create it since it's recycled

Comment: It will slow down list scrolling. My list view has fast scrolling enabled.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as images are of 12mb(even if they are of only 1mb), you have to **scale** them and **downsize** them to the dimensions of your `imageview`.

while you can also check for `outofmemory exception`...

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
//other stuffs like recycling, view holder etc...

    boolean OOME = true;
    int sample = 4;

    while(OOME)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inSampleSize = sample; // tried with 8,12 too
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri, opt);
            bitmap = bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,newWidth,newHeight,true);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            OOME = false;
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            sample *= 2;
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

I also take assumption, you are doing all the **decoding stuff** in a `background thread` to make your `listview scroll` smooth...

While having many problems with `Bitmaps` and `ListView`, this was the best approach i can come with... still I am open for any **changes** or **modifications** or **enhancments**...

Comment: If I handle OutOfMemoryError, while scrolling, crash does not happen but image from the list view disappears. :(
Also, OutOfMemoryError occurs while decoding the file itself and not while setting the bitmap in imageview.

Comment: i told u, u have to use an async thing to decode the bitmap and then set it.... that way it will be visible... Have u thought about using droid-fu library.... ??? It manages/helps a lot....